# reverse iterating and comparing two consecutive elements of std::vector (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm iterating through a list of points that define a circle (closed shape). For each point I'm checking the distance between this one and the next and deciding to subdivide if the distance is bigger than 4.

```
for (vector<Node>::reverse_iterator i = nodes.rbegin(); i != nodes.rend(); ++i) // going through list in reverse
{
    ofVec3f v1 = i->position;
    i += 1;
    ofVec3f v2 = i->position;
    i -= 1;

    float distance = v1.distance(v2);
    if (distance > 4) {
        interpolate(v1, v2);
    }
}
```

The thing is though, I'd like to have it so that the i + 1 element of the last iteration is the first element of the list (because it is a closed shape). I used to have a very handy function in c# that I have here but that I can't use because of how iterators work.

```
int DiffLine::idxFix(int i) {
int c = nodes.size();
if (i < 0) { return c - 1; }
else { return i % c; }
}
```

How could I achieve something similar in my scenario in c++ ?

Comment: aww crap I'm missing an i-- at the end of that loop, let me edit that.
I'm effectively trying to test p5 p4, p4 p3, p3 p2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `i + 1`. If it's `rend()`, then get `v2` from `rbegin()`. You said your structure is a "list", but your use of `+=` tells me you have random access iterators, so I wrote the below assuming you had a random access iterator (such as if `nodes` was a `std::vector`). If that's not the case (eg if `nodes` is actually a `std::list`) this will require slight modification.

```
for (auto i = nodes.rbegin(); i != nodes.rend(); ++i) // going through list in reverse
{

    ofVec3f v1 = i->position;
    ofVec3f v2;
    auto j = i + 1;
    if (j == nodes.rend()) {
        v2 = nodes.rbegin()->position;
    }
    else
    {
        v2 = j->position;
    }

    float distance = v1.distance(v2);
    if (distance > 4) {
        interpolate(v1, v2);
    }
}
```

---

Of course, you don't *have to* use iterators. If this is a random access iterator (again assuming that `nodes` is a `std::vector`), you can use a good-ol' indexed for loop:

```
for (std::size_t i = nodes.size(); i != 0; --i)
{
    ofVec3f v1 = nodes[i % nodes.size()].position;
    ofVec3f v2 = nodes[i - 1].position;

    float distance = v1.distance(v2);
    if (distance > 4) {
        interpolate(v1, v2);
    }
}
```

Note that the above code will check the FIRST element against the LAST element on its first iteration. If that's not acceptable, then we can make some changes.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I've started c++ today and its really completely different from anything I've done before. that first solution seemed to work fine but threw some vector errors for a reason I couldnt explain. the good ol' indexed for loop works like a charm though and is REALLY reassuring to see something that I am familiar with. Why are these not used ever so often ?

Comment: The push to `iterators` was seen to be more object-orienty - thinking of a container of things as a container of things (e.g. a bucket of apples) instead of numbered items on an assembly line. Iterators can be used with all of the `<algorithm>` functions for times when random access won't work. Then you can decouple your algorithms and your containers. The algorithm that sorts a `std::vector` will just as well sort a `std::list`, even though you can't do index into a list like `my_list[5]`. Iterators may also potentially be faster, but most compilers should optimize that benefit away.

Comment: What error did you get with the first solution? I'd rather not leave up bad code in an answer.

Comment: Oops found an error. I was setting `v2 = nodes.begin()->position` when it should have been `v2 = nodes.rbegin()->position`. Is there any reason you're iterating in reverse vs forward?

Comment: in between I added a parameter to the interpolate function, which takes in the current index. so the interpolate function call becomes : interpolate(k, v1, v2);
as I'm not yet familiar with how to recuperate the index from the iterator i just create an int k that i'm incrementing in each loop. when I comment the interpolate function everything is fine but when I call it it gave me a read access violation.
_Mycont was nullptr  "can't decrement vector iterator before begin"

Comment: aye I'm going in reverse because I'm adding one node to the std::vect at each subdivision

Comment: You're adding elements to your `std::vector` within the loop? A vector stores its elements in a continuous block of memory. If the vector gets too big, it needs to move all the elements to new memory. Because of this, adding elements to a vector can potentially invalidate its iterators. That's a potential cause of the issue with the iterator code.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'll use an indexed for loop for this specific case then, in the case of an iterator I imagine I would have to make a buffer and apply all the changes after the loop ?

Comment: Yeah something like a "work queue" or buffer. But then you need to store the concept of what a "do work to this vector" queue is, and ain't nobody got time for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the wrapper for a random access iterator, that performs the similar actions as the c# method:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
class LoopWrapper {
 public:
  LoopWrapper(const RandomAccessIterator& first,
              const RandomAccessIterator& last)
      : first_(first), dist_(last-first) {}
  typename RandomAccessIterator::value_type& operator*() {
    return *(first_ + pos_);
  }
  LoopWrapper& operator++() {
    pos_++;
    if (pos_ == dist_) {
      pos_ = 0;
      wrapped_ = true;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  LoopWrapper& operator--() {
    pos_--;
    if (pos_ < 0) pos_ = dist_ - 1;
    return *this;
  }
  LoopWrapper operator+(int offset) {
    LoopWrapper result = *this;
    result.pos_ += offset;
    result.pos_ %= dist_;
    if (result.pos_ < 0) result.pos_ += dist_;
    return result;
  }
  LoopWrapper operator-(int offset) {
    LoopWrapper result = *this;
    result.pos_ -= offset;
    result.pos_ %= dist_;
    if (result.pos_ < 0) result.pos_ += dist_;
    return result;
  }
  operator RandomAccessIterator() { return first_ + pos_; }
  bool Done() const { return wrapped_; }

 private:
  const RandomAccessIterator first_;
  const int dist_;
  int pos_ = 0;
  bool wrapped_ = false;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
  for (auto i = LoopWrapper(v.begin(), v.end()); !i.Done(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", " << *(i + 1) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```